# How to store a value while a page is running ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I am trying to store an email address while a page is running and refer to it in my controller. How can i do this? Currently i am doing this:

```
 var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, viewModel.EmailEntry),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "PasswordReset")
                    };
                    var claimsIdentity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity));
```

But i don't really want to use a cookie just to store the email address throughout the pages execution.

Comment: You could use Session, which is meant for temporary server-side storage spanning multiple requests by a single user